# How to create this select2 bootstrap array from mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create this using the output rows of mySQL?
The fields i want for the `id` is `card_id` and for `text` is `card_text`.

I use

```
while($card= mysql_fetch_assoc($all_cards)) { }
```

here is the array that I want to export

```
{
            id: 0,
            text: 'enhancement'
        }, {
            id: 1,
            text: 'bug'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            text: 'duplicate'
        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something ?

This should works :

```
$result = array();
while($card= mysql_fetch_assoc($all_cards)) { 
    $result[]= array(
        'id' => $card->card_id, 
        'text' => $cart->card_text
    );
}
var_dump(json_encode($result));
```